# $injector:nomod Module 'app' is not available! Firefox Only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I'm stuck on this, I read everything about it, but I can't figure it out, I declare my `<script>` app.js before using the ng-app and still I got this error :

Failed to instantiate module app due to:

> [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled
>   the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure
>   that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

The error only appear on Firefox.

**Html :**

```
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="css\bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="css\component.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="css\app.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js\modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js\ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js\app.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="app">>

    <div class="top row">

        <top-header></top-header>

        <home-carousel></home-carousel>

    </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

**js :**

```
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

`app.directive('topHeader', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'topHeader.html',
    controller: function ($scope, $window) {

    name = $window.location.pathname;
    n = name.lastIndexOf("/");
    name = name.substring(n + 1);
    if (name === "index.html" || name === "")
        $scope.current = '1';
    else if (name === "resume.html")
        $scope.current = '2';
    else if (name === "projects.html")
        $scope.current = '3';

    }
 };
});

app.directive('homeCarousel', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'homeCarousel.html',
    controller: function ($scope)
    {
        $scope.myInterval = 5000;
        $scope.noWrapSlides = false;
        $scope.active = 0;
        var slides = $scope.slides = [];
        var currIndex = 0;

        $scope.addSlide = function()
        {
            slides.push(
            {
                image: "image" + currIndex+ ".jpg",
                id: currIndex++
            });
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            $scope.addSlide();
        }
    }
};
});`

Comment: I am missing a closing `>` on `<html lang="en-US"`..

Comment: Not it's my fault i was trying to edit it at the same time as you the  '>' is not missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the backslash here to a slash

```
<script src="js\app.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

This might be throwing your browser off.

Comment: OH no you're right ! The error went on bootstrap.ui ! Thank you !